# Best way to create multiple users with different variable in BeforeTestRun Hook - Specflow

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow

Hi I have a question,

Currently I am creating an user under the `users` location and i also want to create a user under an `admin` location.

My Specflow Scenario looks like this.

```
@createUser
Scenario Outline: Do Something to created users
    Given A user has already been created under <location>
    When I do something with the user
    Then I expected something to happen
Examples:
| location |
| admin    |
| users    |
```

And my BeforeTestRun looks like this:

```
[BeforeTestRun()]
   public static void BeforeTestRun(string location // I would like to pass this 
variable from the scenario examples table)
   {
       CreateEmployeeForTestRun(location);
       ...
            

   }
```

I only want the users to be created once at the start of the execution and i clean them up at the end, The above scenario is just a simplified version of my complex one.

I also have multiple scenarios that will use this 2 different users under different location.

Also more location will be added in the future hence I am looking to pass the table variable as a parameter into the BeforeTestRun hook, I have not been successful as of yet and not sure if its possible to do with specflow, Also I am sure that there might be a better solution to this,  I want to avoid as much of repetition as I can.

Any Ideas/Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Given there is an admin user
And there is a user
```

Is a good starting point.  It would be better if you could be more precise about the non-admin user e.g.

```
Given there is an admin user
And there is a customer
```

You should implement these steps, something like

```
Given 'there is an admin' do
  @admin = create_admin
end

Given 'there is a customer' do
  @customer = create_customer
end
```

and defer how you create users to helper methods.

Once you have that you can create

`Given there is an admin and a customer`

and implement as

```
Given 'there is an admin and a customer' do
  @admin, @customer = create_admin, create_customer
end
```

Your helper methods would be something like

```
module UserCreationStepHelper
  def create_admin
    ...

  def create_customer
    ...
end
World UserCreationStepHelper
```

caveat: Above is ruby cucumber, you will need to translate. You should be able to get help with this at cucumber.io